# Why is "if ("ss"==0)" result on true;

Tags: php, if-statement

Am learning, So don't kill me for asking. lol

```
if ("ss"==0)
   print "TRUE";
else
   print "FALSE";
```

Comment: Found it. kinda dulicate question
stackoverflow.com/questions/5894350/why-does-0-hello-return-true-in-php?rq=1

Comment: You are not comparing your letters as you would think.  Since you are not checking the type (===)...  You are comparing them to the values of the letters according to the ascii chart I believe?